# Unity: Spin wheels to move vehicle

Tags: unity, vehicle

I am just getting started with Unity and I'd like to ask a question. If I have a "Vehicle" object that has two children: "FrontWheel" and "BackWheel" (both 'wheels' are cylinders), how should I set everything up such that I can move the entire vehicle by turning its wheels?

When I apply a torque to "FrontWheel", the vehicle starts to move, but instead of the whole thing the moving together, the chassis is rolling on the cylinders [and eventually falls off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Khxh.jpg).

How can I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make sure to parent the chassis to the wheels. It sounds like you have them as separate objects rather than parented together?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many special case considerations with the simulation of wheeled vehicle physics that you are unlikely to get a satisfying result by simply torquing cylindrical collision primitives. You should consider instead using the special [Wheel Collider](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-WheelCollider.html) component.

Comment: For the moment I'm not trying to make something fun. I just want to find a way to move the entire vehicle by only turning its wheels.

Comment: If you're sure you want to keep going with simple cylinders, try using a hinge joint to attach the wheels to the chassis: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/HingeJoint.html

Comment: It's not about making it fun, it is just that it won't work well if you apply torque, you'll have collision problems.